# How can I get a text box ID in PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a text box

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" value="" name="Name_Code" id="Name_Code">
```

In the `lookup` function, I need to eveluate the control ID. How I can get this ID without knowing the exact ID?

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
function lookup(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(currentId);
    }
};
```

Comment: `$(this)` won't work in your case - it has no context. What ID are you trying to get? We need more details and more code here. Also, please go back to your old questions and Accept correct answers or the ones you ended up using.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. You present HTML and JavaScript code but asking for something in PHP. You could please describe the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: No wonder that it doesen't work. The local variable $(this) contains no content. Add another parameter to give the function an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `event` to your function and it's in there.

First add this to your input tag:

```
onkeyup="lookup(event, this.value);"
```

And the function will now be:

```
function lookup(event, inputString) {
   ...
   var sender = event.target || event.srcElement;
   var currentId = sender.id;
   ...
}
```

Anyhow, you're misusing jQuery. Correct usage will be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#Name_Code").bind("keyup", function() {
      var inputString = $(this).val();
      if(inputString.length == 0) {
           // Hide the suggestion box.
           $('#suggestions').hide();
       } else {
          var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
           alert(currentId);
       }
   });
});
```

Test case is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/LpbW9/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this may be its works

```
onkeyup="lookup(this.id);"

function lookup(id){
    alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using jquery binding if you use jquery.

For your existing setup, this will work

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="lookup(this);" value="" name="Name_Code" id="Name_Code">

function lookup(obj) {
    if(obj.value.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        var currentId = obj.id; //note that I passed -this- and not -this.value-
        alert(currentId);
    }
};
```

Since you already have jquery I suggest you should do this

```
<input type="text" value="" name="Name_Code" id="Name_Code">

$('#Name_Code').keyup(lookup);

function lookup() {
    $this = $(this); //since we have the jquery object
    if($this.val().length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        var currentId = $this.attr('id'); //note that I passed -this- and not -this.value-
        alert(currentId);
    }
};
```